# Installing large packages in aem

Tags: aem

I need to install large-sized packages in a new instance I am configuring.  I am using package-manager for this but it is taking very long time for installation. 
Is there some other way this can be done?
Additionally, it would be helpful if I can get information about physical location where DAM packages are stored. (Example: is there some way I can find path of DAM packages on my localhost?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried the resources online? a quick google search returns these results: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToInstallPackagesUsingRepositoryInstall.html https://edivad.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/installing-big-packages-in-cq5crx/  http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/43179911102/how-to-efficiently-copy-large-amounts-of-content

Answer (score 3):

To install large content packages we always use `curl`. The largest packages we installed so far were about 15GB but it should also work with larger packages.

The `curl`command looks like this:

```
curl -u <user>:<password> \
    -F file=@"name of zip file" \
    -F name="name of package" \ 
    -F force=true \
    -F install=true \
    http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp
```

There are a lot more helpful `curl` commands. Just google for "AEM curl commands" and you will find a lot of cheat sheets like the following:

https://gist.github.com/joemaffia/dd55e4c43a24c4948e8d

Answer (score 2):

Since package manager works on HTTP, it is limited by all the issues of HTTP. There are other alternatives and one of the best one is [Grabbit](https://github.com/TWCable/grabbit)

It makes use of [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://web.archive.org/web/20230208164356/https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) to ensure the speed of transfer. You can read more appreciation about it on Adobe's [Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160422165805/http://blogs.adobe.com:80/experiencedelivers/experience-management/time-warner-cable-shares-open-source-tools/).

Alternatively, you can also use [Vault Remote Copy](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/rcp.html) which may work depending on your machine and network bandwidth as it does not require the packaging overhead.

Alternatively, if you have the luxury of offline instances, you can also use the oak2oak migration utility from Apache. More details can be found [here](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/migration.html).

Packaging requires zip creation and uses a lot of memory and CPU so large packages will always be an issue therefore the options mentioned above will help. It is normally advisable to make smaller packages and install them in chunks. You can use curl commands to split the packages on super nodes and install them (for example a large DAM repo can be split by root paths or other categories like starting alphabet etc.)

The DAM could be stored in S3 or file system depending on your instance. If your instances are carbon copies then you can, in theory, copy over the datastore and attach to the nodestore. This is not recommended but is an option if your instance is too large for conventional methods stated above.