# Deploying AEM projects using Maven

Tags: maven, aem

We are new to Adobe and going to start working with it. Our Build Tool is maven, CI tool- Jenkins. As we are using Maven as a build tool. How to deploy our artifacts to jetty web server?

In short, Can we deploy artifacts of adobe project using maven? or do we need to have plugins for jenkins to deploy artifacts to different environment. I have came across
Maven-jetty and cargo plugin for deployments using maven to jetty webserver.

Comment: Generally, for Jenkins deployment you’d deploy through package manager which has HTTP endpoint through which you can deploy packages. You can find some of the curl commands you can use here: https://gist.github.com/sergeimuller/2916697.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy your project with Maven I suggest that you use the `content-package-maven-plugin`. You can read more about the details in [Adobes official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/dev-tools/vlt-mavenplugin.html). The basic principal is the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.24</version>
    <configuration>
        <userId>admin</userId>
        <password>admin</password>
        <targetURL>http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is a simple example that would deploy to a default AEM installation on your local machine (or same machine as `mvn` runs).

If you are running your build on Jenkins you might want to consider *not* using Maven to deploy your artifacts. Usually, you have multiple AEM instances running to which you want to deploy your content packages: "author" and "publish".

For the builds running on Jenkins I would suggest deploying your artifacts using `curl`. I wrote an answer about uploading and installing content packages using `curl` on Stack Overflow: [How to install large (content) packages in AEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331679/190823).

Comment: Hi Jens, Is there anyway that we can hide credentials of the server?

Comment: Yes. You could define Maven `properties` with default values. Lets call the property for the user `aemuser`. You then would change the configuration to `<userId>${aemuser}</userId>`. Then you could build the project and pass the username as command line argument: `mvn install -Daemuser=myuser`. But I am not sure you want to do this. The method above should only be used for local development and not to _really_ deploy to your production environments etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to use the Aem maven archetype to create your project. It will come with the default settings, POM entries so that you can change your configuration to deploy it to the required environments.
Here is the link - 
https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype